# Does it work? Veritable indoor garden

Tags: indoors, office-gardening

I moved in a house without balcony nor garden nor communal garden, very sad. I was considering the idea of having an indoor garden with LED lights, like the Veritable indoor gardens, or there are manu others actually.

What is your experience with this kind of stuff? Does it work at least for having some green around?

Comment: Veritable gardens are usually supplied with edible plant seeds, often herbs - are you wanting to grow herbs or edible plants? Or just decorative green plants (houseplants in other words)? Is there good daylight in your house/room?

Comment: Hi Bamboo, I just wish to grow something that looks like a plant, but it is not the usual boring office plant. I like the idea of growing basil and parsley and mint, maybe to take away a leave for cooking once in a while and feel myself very countryside, but mostly for having some perfume around the room and allow some variations every sometime. The even sell rosemary. The daylight in these rooms is not great, Some sunlight enters the window directly, but stays for few hours only, I reckon not enough for herbs needing direct sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about lack of sun being a problem for herbs, but there are other drawbacks. None of these give off a perfume; like many aromatic plants, they only release scent if the leaves are bruised. Rosemary in particular will not do well long term inside, it really needs to be outdoors, being a hardy shrub that reaches 6 x 6 feet. Basil is also only an annual plant, so you'd need to replace it regularly. Mint needs a large pot and regular splitting up, otherwise it looks a mess after a few months because their growth habit is to spread via underground stolons, popping up a foot or two away. They can't do that in pots, so usually, the middle dies back and all you have is a few leggy branches round the edges, which is when it's time to decant, cut in half and repot the halves separately. I think that Veritable garden really is only intended for very short term use when planted with herbs, there's not enough space for them to grow for very long.

You could choose houseplants suited to medium light conditions and group them together in a suitable spot, choosing different height plants to create an attractive display, although they would be just the usual sorts of plants you see in home and office environments. Suggestions for this type of grouping would include the following:

*Dracaena fragrans*; a larger plant of *Dracaena marginata* (sometimes these are sold as quite small plants); *Ficus benjamina* (variegated or plain green, but they hate draughts); *Schefflera arboricola* (variegated or plain green) - these will give height. Midsized plants include *Syngonium*; *Chlorophytum comosum* (spider plant); *Aglaonema* (various colours); *Sansevieria* (Mother in Law's tongue) - there are other, shorter varieties such as *S. 'Golden Hahni'* instead of choosing the usual *S. trifasciata*; ZZ plant (*Zamioculcas zamiifolia*). There's also the ubiquitous *Epripremnum aureum* (Devil's Ivy or Pothos) but that will need to be up on something so it can trail, or trained up a support.

There are many more to choose from; many plants grown in the home do best in medium to bright light, out of direct sun, and away from heat sources.
Grouping plants together also helps with air humidity around them, because they  create a bit of a micro environment for themselves - heated homes can be arid places.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, so when you say planted with herbs you mean something like basi, parsley, maybe oregano or thyme, just something small for cooking basically? They claim they can grow chili and wild strawberry plants, does it sound realistic to you?

Comment: Yes, all those herbs you mention, but they don't stay small, that's the trouble, they want to get much bigger - oregano makes a spreading low plant up to 2 feet across in the ground, whereas Thyme makes a woody shrub about 2 feet tall and wide. Chili maybe will grow but needs sun to ripen the peppers,, wild strawberry, no - without sun, no ripe fruit, and they make a spreading patch in the ground too. Parsley likes cool temperatures and you need quite a lot of it to be useful...